# Spring validator error code is not auto resolve

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, localization, spring-validator

Message source config:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:locale/normal/message", "classpath:locale/validation/message");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

Spring validator:

```
@Component
public class MyAccountValidator implements Validator {

    @Autowired
    MyAccountService myAccountService;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {       
        return MyAccount.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

        MyAccount myAccount = (MyAccount) target;

        MyAccount myAccountDb = myAccountService.findByUserId(myAccount.getUserId());

        if (myAccountDb == null) {
            errors.reject("myAccount.id.not_found");
        }
    }
}
```

message_en.properties:

```
myAccount.id.not_found=Your id is not found.
```

hibernate validator:

```
@NotNull(message="{myAccount.id.not_found}")
private String password;
```

Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/validate" }, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String validate(Model model, @RequestBody @Valid MyAccount myAccount, BindingResult bindingResult, Locale locale) throws JsonProcessingException {

    System.out.println("myAccount user id = " + myAccount.getUserId());

    String msg = "";
    List<ObjectError> errors = bindingResult.getAllErrors();
    for (ObjectError error : errors ) {
        msg = msg + (error.getObjectName() + " - " + error.getCode() + " - " + error.getDefaultMessage()) + "\n";
    }                       

    return msg;
}
```

In my controller, `error.getDefaultMessage()` is always showing null value for the Spring validator error code `errors.reject("myAccount.id.not_found");`, it cannot be resolved automatically.

When I try hibernate validator as you can see in the field annotation above, it is working fine, `@NotNull(message="{myAccount.id.not_found}")` can be resolved perfectly in each of the locale automatically.

Do I miss out any configuration? Why the Spring validator error code not working automatically?

PS: My I18N configuration should be correct, all my JSP can display the text correctly.

Comment: You probably didn't configure a **LocalValidatorFactoryBean** yet. You may take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692179/spring-boot-validation-message-is-not-being-resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been searching for whole day, probably there is no answer for my question... I conclude some of my findings:

1) Reading through lot of tutorials, all of them display the error message in JSP view, so they could probably get it work like this: `<form:errors path="*" cssClass="error" element="div"/>`, error code will got resolved to locale message automatically. But in my case, I want to get the error message via ajax, so, to resolve the error code in controller, I have to do it manually, unfortunately I have to inject `messagesource` and `locale` in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/validate" }, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String validate(Model model, @RequestBody @Valid MyAccount myAccount, BindingResult bindingResult, Locale locale) throws JsonProcessingException {

    System.out.println("myAccount user id = " + myAccount.getUserId());

    String msg = "";
    List<ObjectError> errors = bindingResult.getAllErrors();
    for (ObjectError error : errors ) {
        msg = msg + (messageSource.getMessage(error, locale)) + "\n";
    }                       

    return msg;
}
```

2) Have a read on the [Resolving codes to error messages](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-conversion), the resolver is to resolve the error code to one or multiple message code, it doesn't help to map the message code to the message values in the `messagesource`. I have misunderstand the term between `error code` and `message code`.

If someone who has the solution, please share...